# This program is not working, it says MultiDegreeView object has no attribute values, but i want to use the values() function of dictionary

Tags: python, dataset, networkx

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib as plt

def plot_deg_dist(G):
    all_degrees = nx.degree(G).values()
    unique_degrees = list(set(all_degrees))

    count_of_degrees = []

    for i in unique_degrees:
        x = all_degrees.count(i)
        count_of_degrees.append(x)
    
    plt.pyplot.plot(unique_degrees, count_of_degrees)
    plt.pyplot.show()

G = nx.read_pajek('karate.paj')

plot_deg_dist(G)
```

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "datasets.py", line 19, in 
plot_deg_dist(G)
File "datasets.py", line 5, in plot_deg_dist
all_degrees = nx.degree(G).values()
AttributeError: 'MultiDegreeView' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `nx.degree(G).values`
According to [doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) You can use,

```
list(G.degree(list(G.nodes)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a dictionary first

```
all_degrees = dict(nx.degree(G)).values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with list comprehention

```
def plot_deg_dist(G):
    all_degrees = [degree for node, degree in G.degree()]
    unique_degrees = list(set(all_degrees))

    count_of_degrees = []
    for degree in unique_degrees:
        count = all_degrees.count(degree)
        count_of_degrees.append(count)
    
    plt.plot(unique_degrees, count_of_degrees, 'ro-')
```